# How to add txt record to dns configuration godaddy using .NET Core? Is this possible via code?

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, dns, txt

I got txt record from dns server of the domain but currently we try to add txt record to the godaddy but technically is that possible using C# in .NET Core?

Comment: Where do you point your domain? If you point your domain to Godaddy name server, then you can just login to their control panel -> DNS settings, then you can add your TXT records.

Comment: @MarkSpencer Yes, that,s I Know. But I need to add through C# code